# Cleanup the [weak] and [strong] tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

The tags [strong](/questions/tagged/strong) and [weak](/questions/tagged/weak) are both weak tags. I suggest retagging  to more descriptive tags such as [strong-typing](/questions/tagged/strong-typing), [weak-typing](/questions/tagged/weak-typing), [weak-references](/questions/tagged/weak-references) etc.

A couple other cleanup suggestions for weak tags:

- Make [weakly-typed](/questions/tagged/weakly-typed) a synonym of [weak-typing](/questions/tagged/weak-typing) (or re-tag)
- [weaknesses](/questions/tagged/weaknesses) Burn it!

[Total list of all questions needing clean-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strong+or+weak+or+weakness+or+weakly-typed)

Comment: Since your edits are currently suggested edits, each edit has to go through the suggested edit review queue. If there are other issues with the post such as formatting or grammar, fix those too. This will make your edits less likely to be rejected as too minor.